# Apostrophes in SQL selecting the whole table

Tags: sql, apostrophe

I had this weird bug in my company's code from an SQL sentence, that was basically updating all the rows from a table when what we wanted was just to update a single one. The code was the following.

```
UPDATE table SET 'disconnections'=value WHERE 'connections'=(SELECT MAX('connections') FROM table)
```

Where the apostrophe surrounding the column names where obviously wrong. So this was updating all the rows in the table; we removed them and the sentence worked as expected. What was the deal with that?

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using? Are you sure the character is ' and not ` ?

Comment: tag the correct DBMS please

Comment: In ANSI SQL single quotes are for string literals, e.g. `'some text'`. Use double quotes for identifiers, e.g. `"column-name"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in `MAX('connections')`. Obviously you want to use `` instead of just single quotas `''`. In your case `'connections'` is a string constant not a field name. So `MAX(constant) = constant`. This condition is TRUE for all records in your table since it doesn't depend on a field with name `connections`.

I guess it is MySQL so if you want to refer a field name you should use `` instead of ''.